# Multiple 'or' on while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi, I'm a python newbie so please be easy on me :)
Let's say I have:

```
while input != 'n' or input != 'r' or input != 'e':
```

is there a way to shorten that statement?

Comment: `input` is a built-in function, don't use it as a variable name.

Comment: Also, this code is equivalent to `while True:`. Try to think why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`not in`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) to test for membership:

```
# Please do not name a variable `input` -- doing so overshadows the built-in.
while inp not in ('n', 'r', 'e'):
```

---

Also, depending on the purpose of this code, you may wish to use [`str.lower`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) like so:

```
while inp.lower() not in ('n', 'r', 'e'):
```

Doing this will allow you to handle uppercase letters.

---

**Edit in response to comment:**

There are two ways to build this loop.  The first is like this:

```
player_input = raw_input("Enter a character: ")
while player_input not in ('n', 'r', 'e'):
    player_input = raw_input("Enter a character: ")
```

The second is like this:

```
while True:
    player_input = raw_input("Enter a character: ")
    if player_input in ('n', 'r', 'e'):
        break
```

While I personally prefer the second solution, both of them ultimately do the same thing so you can choose whichever you like.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense! I can make it a list or tuple or something like that and use 'not in'. Yes, i just realized that after I submitted this question, I am now using player_input instead of just input.

Let me add up another question since it is slightly related. Say I want a loop that keeps going while the user has not input either n, r, e.

I have a little idea on how to do that using raw_input, but I would love to see how an expert do it.

Thank you iCodez!

Answer (score 4):

You can write:

```
while not input in "enr":
    ...
```

or (and more clearly):

```
while not input in ('e', 'r', 'n'):
    ..
```

Answer (score -1):

```
l=['n','r','e']
while input not in l:
```

Hope this helps!